# Logging out from Facebook with access_token, but active sessions remain

Tags: facebook, session, logout

I am using the `Facebook API` in a `C++` application with `libcurl`.
Logging in works good, I can retrieve some user information after the user has registered my application. 
The problem is, when I want to log the user out via

`https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token=RETRIEVED_TOKEN&confirm=1&next=http://www.google.com` ,
there are still remaining active sessions in my account settings (security).

I don't want these sessions to remain as the logout should clean these.
How can I smoothly clean those active sessions when logging out?
Do I have to add the `APP_ID` to the URL?

Comment: Active sessions? How? Is there's any use of a browser or something? A session needs a cookie to work.

Comment: Hi! I mean that in the menu "Security" in the account settings within your facebook account, there are several active sessions displayed which have an "unknown device". I want to clear these sessions by logging out, but it doesn't work, yet. I have also tried to add the client_id of my application, but no change.

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't think that you have any control over that, the only other way I can think of that you can use to log the user out is by using the [FB.logout method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/) of the js sdk, but that's not a good solution for you. You might want to report a bug for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, using javascript isn't a solution for me, as I use Curl to post HTTP requests out of a C++ application. Where could I post this bug? Isn't there another solution to close active sessions? What does FB.logout do internally?

Comment: This is the facebook bug system: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs. As for the *FB.logout*, you can check the [source @ github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-js-sdk/blob/master/src/core/auth.js). Why do you care so much if the session on the facebook end was removed or not?

Comment: Thanks for providing the links! I do care about removing the sessions because I want to leave the account in a clean state. I use the connection to facebook just to authenticate the user, then want to close the connection. Also, I don't want to leave so many connections from an "Unknown Device".

Comment: I found out why active session aren't cleared: As UserAgent I used "Mozilla/5.0". When using "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)", there are no remaining active session, but the redirection of the URLs is different. Why is it dependent on the user agent which URLs are returned?

Comment: I'm not sure, I also had no experience with that.. Maybe just different output designed for different browsers

Comment: It is not just different output, but different web pages that are returned. Even if I used a known user agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0", the active sessions remain. I would not mind about these sessions, but I think the app users will do.

Comment: The vast majority of users are not aware of this thing. You really think that most users even go to the *Account Settings*? How many out of those click the *Security* tab? and out of those, how many check their sessions?  As long as you use the logout method provided by facebook you're probably ok with 99% of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was missing in my code: The lib that was encapsulating libcurl to perform requests on facebook wasn't cleaning up properly.

So the fix was to do curl_easy_cleanup() on my curl handle in the destructor of my session object. Now there are no active sessions on facebook anymore.

While debugging, I found another error in my code concerning curl: If you want to do curl_easy_getinfo(handle, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, buf) you MAY NOT delete  after the function call as curl holds the buffer. 
Furthermore, I don't have any memory leaks.
Thanks for your help!